# Creating an ammeter?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

Three resistances AB, BC, CD are joined in series and placed across the terminals of a galvanometer. The resistance of the galvanometer is 15 ohm and it gives full scale deflection for a current of 5 milliampere. Find the value of each of the resistances so that the instrument will serve as a multi-range ammeter, using external connections A and B for the 0-1 ampere range, to A and C for the range 0-0.1 ampere, and to A and D for the range 0-10milliampere.

I assume this needs some kind of simultaneous equation solving, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: Look up meaning of Galvanometer!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I know what a galvanometer is, that isn't the question.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at our homework policy-in-making: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange